# Why is the Aztec/Nahuatl Syllabary incomplete?

Tags: book, aztec, painting

I am looking at [this](https://ancientscripts.livejournal.com/100602.html):

[image]

Why is it not complete? Obviously they must not be able to find these glyphs, but what exactly does that mean? Where did they find these existing glyphs anyways? Are they scattered around? Basically wondering if one could piece together the puzzle to show how this was constructed (just a quick intro). Do they know if the glyphs are out there somewhere on one of the digitized photographs of stone carvings or other inscriptions, and they just haven't been deciphered? Or are they completely lost and we have little to no hope of completing this thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Sources? Research?

Answer (score 3):

The phonetic portion of the script is an [abugida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abugida): don't expect all the cells in the table to be populated, nor for the symbols within to relate to each other. According to Alfonso Lacadena in [*Regional Scribal Traditions: Methodological Implications for the Decipherment of Nahuatl Writing*](http://www.mesoweb.com/pari/publications/journal/804/PARI0804.pdf), the Aztec script is principally symbolic, with limited phonetic components:

> Nahuatl writing is basically logographic, with an incipient or undeveloped phoneticism, restricted to the utilization of rebus for logograms and a limited repertory of signs used in phonetic mode, without integration into a true conventional syllabary (see Prem 1992; Lockhart 1992:327-330; Boone 2000:31-38; León-Portilla 2003:41).

The "limited" phonetic aspect of the script means that even if the Nahuatl language uses the sounds that are blank in your syllabary (I do not know this), that doesn't necessarily mean that they ever needed a phonetic symbol.

Even the well-documented and well-researched [Mayan script](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/mayan.htm), which is more biased towards syllabic symbols than logographic ones, has blanks in the syllabary (somewhat fewer than the Nahuatl one).

Comment: Haven't looked into this one, but when I see holes in a syllabary's vowel/consonant matrix, I usually assume that language doesn't actually use that particular combo enough to have needed a symbol for it. In fact, I believe for Semitic languages, it was traditionaly almost a many-to-one relation for every vowel, which is how they ended up with Abjads (which when borrowed by Greek which didn't have that nice feature, spurred the invention of the first alphabet)

Comment: @T.E.D. It may be, and my answer would be better if it specified which sounds were in use at all; but Lacadena did specifically mention a "limited repertory of signs used in phonetic mode".